# Avoid Keyboard Pull Activity Layout when shown android

Tags: android, android-keypad

When i focus on edittext in my application the keyboard open and push my activity layout above the keyboard. The only option i have is to check if the keyboard is open then make the buttons that is pulled above keyboard invisible. I wonder if there is a simple way to disable the layout to get pulled up because this is a common error in every application i build.  Also can someone tell me how to check when the keyboard is shown or hide. thanks.

Updates : From my manifest

```
    <activity  android:name=".Defi"  android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"   android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
      Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

this could help

better look at here[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1109108/580532)

Comment: yes but how can i place a condition when it is visible do something else do nothing

Answer (score 2):

i think u should change in manifiest

```
<activity android:name=".yourActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this link, [re-sizing the app](http://blog.vogella.com/2010/10/25/android-windowsoftinputmode/)

```
  <activity android:name=".TodoEdit"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity 
  android:name="Tollywood"
  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"></activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this in you manifest :

```
 <activity
       android:name=".MainActivity"
       android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" >
 </activity>
```

This will help you and wont pull layout up and also useful in handling configuration change when activity is transferred from `Portrait` mode to `Landscape` mode.

Comment: so what's your problem? Please provide images of issue you are having.

Comment: i upload an image check question